# Access a dynamic colspan value

Tags: php

I'm accessing a a value stored in an array using, `$array2[$arr[$count]]`. This prints the value perfectly what I expect using an echo in PHP.

Bt when I put this into a table colspan it doesn't give what I expect.

```
echo '<td colspan=$array2[$arr[$count]]>';
```

If someone knows please let me know the mistake I have made...

Comment: are you seeing this exactly as it's seen here by any chance? Try changing the single quotes to double quotes, or even better grab the value first to a single variable and then include that like this '<td colspan='.$myValue.'>';

Comment: with simple quote ( ' ) variable are not interpreted. You have tu use double quote ( " ).

Comment: I prefer to keep the single quotes and join my variables because when using code-highlighting it makes it easier to see where variables are used as they tend to pick up a different colour to the strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using single-quotes. Variable values do not get interpolated when they're in single-quotes.

Use double-quotes instead (with curly braces):

```
echo "<td colspan=\"{$array2[$arr[$count]]}\">";
```

Or, single-quotes, with concatenation:

```
echo '<td colspan="' . $array2[$arr[$count]] . '">';
```

Or, using [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprinft) (more neater, in my opinion):

```
echo sprinf('<td colspan=%d>', $array2[$arr[$count]]);
```

Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your echo code to:

```
echo "<td colspan=$array2[$arr[$count]]>";
```

This is because the string inside single quotes is interpreted literally. 
So the colspan would equal `$array2[$arr[$count]]` which is obviously not a valid value.

Comment: The second part is just a copy of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19402227/1438393). Why are you doing that?

Comment: Thanx for replying Patrick.. First one gives me an error like
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ']' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHIS2\CreateTheForm.php on line 159...............

But others work really well.... :) Thanks for replying and explaining.... :)

Comment: Removed the downvote. But you might want to read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78658) :)

Comment: @AmalMurali sure, sorry for that :)